# Primary security risks of Bitcoin QT API use

Tags: bitcoin-core, api

When using an API to operate Bitcoin QT remotely, which security concerns should I be most worried about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin-Cores RPC API is not meant to be available on the public internet. It's not hardened enough and the authentication (HTTP BASE AUTH) is **not** safe.

If you want to connect to the RPC-API over the internet, you have a couple of options...

- use VPN (openVPN, etc.)
- use stunnel
- use Apache with a reverse proxy and enable SSL (probably most easy to setup)

Also have a look at the 0.12 release notes:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/release-notes/release-notes-0.12.0.md#rpc-ssl-support-dropped